# Barnard's Exact Test in R

Tags: r

I am performing Barnard's exact test for 2X2 contingency table. I found https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Exact/Exact.pdf for doing Barnard's test in R. My R  version is 3.2.2 . I am trying to install package `Exact`, but it seems the package is not available for R version 3.2.2 . Is it so? How do you implement Barnard's test in R ?

Edit:

> install.packages("Exact")

It gives the following message

`Warning: unable to access index for repository https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CRAN/src/contrib
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2
Warning message:
package ‘Exact’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)`

> library(Exact)
>
> Error in library(Exact) : there is no package called ‘Exact’

Comment: Can you post the code you used to install it? My guess is you had a typo.
Also, why don't you update to the latest version?

Comment: This needs more info. On 3.3.2 I cannot reproduce that it cannot be installed and loaded.

Comment: I don't see any R version dependency listed on the package's [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Exact/index.html). That said, R 3.2.2 is more than 2 years old. You'll likely run into dependency issues with other packages as time goes on. If admin rights for installation / upgrade isn't an issue, maybe consider switching to a more recent version of R?

Comment: What is this link in the warning message http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CRAN/src/contrib/ ?

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with the CRAN mirror you've selected. Choose a different CRAN mirror with `chooseCRANmirror()`. Selection "1" usually works just fine. After you change your mirror, try running `install.packages("Exact")` again.

Comment: @MrFlick It works. Thank you so much. By selection "1", did you mean `0-cloud[https]`?

Comment: Yes. 0-Cloud. Not all mirrors keep older stuff around.

Answer (score 1):

Did you type the following **exactly**? (See what I did there)

`install.packages("Exact")`

Comment: Does it work in your latest R version?

Comment: Yup, worked on a few versions. I misread your version number though, thought I tested your specific version but I don't have it installed.